# Changing Date time using DateTime - format(dateFormatString, timezone)

Tags: apex, datetime, date

In below execute anonymous code I am seeing a strange behaviour.

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.newInstanceGMT(2019, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0);
system.debug('myDateTime === ' + myDateTime);
DateTime newDateTime = myDateTime.addHours(16);
system.debug('newDateTime === ' + newDateTime.format('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'America/Phoenix'));
```

[image]

I see the year changes from 2019 to 2020 , which is unexpected. Is there anyway I could have 2019 instead of 2020 here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last format should use `yyyy` and not `YYYY`

```
system.debug('newDateTime === ' + newDateTime.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'America/Phoenix'));
```

correctly returns `2019-12-30 09:00:00`

Frankly, not sure why `YYYY` fails while `yyyy` works, since I can't find documentation that uses the uppercase version at all.

==Update==

I found it. Per [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) doc, `YYYY` refers to "Week Year" and that week, if you look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year), would correctly be in 2020.

So that's the answer.

Comment: Nice catch! That's strange that YYYY is different from yyyy